# Login flow for portal user profile not working

Tags: visualforce

I used  [customized login flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow_visualforce.htm&type=5) to detect the user's browser at point of entry to Salesforce. Based on browser used by user we are showing custom warning message.

My functionality is working as expected for all profile but for portal user its not showing warning message. Portal profile having access to custom page EVT_loginFlow. I added login flow for portal user as shown below in screen. Do we need to do anything for portal user profile ?

[image: Lo]

Comment: Does your portal user profile has the vf page assigned ? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yes, portal user profile is having access rights assigned to EVT_loginFlow page. There is no error, it seems Login flow is not getting called. After login page is getting redirect to default tab.

Comment: Have you set a debug log on the portal user to see if there are any exceptions or if the VF page is being bypassed?